# How do you connect ending of word "Didn't" , with word "Do"?

Tags: pronunciation

I find it hard to pronounce these two words together quickly, so I thought I must be missing some sound or something that connects them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need a better description of your problem. What happens when you try to pronounce "didn't do"?

Comment: In Recieved Pronunciation there is a momentary pause between the  't' and the 'd' but in many dialects the 't' is dropped giving "I didn' do that".

Comment: The /t/ goes first, and the /n/ becomes syllabic and the second /d/ is tapped, so you wind up saying "did'n'do" (/'dɪɾṇ'du/).

Comment: @BoldBen - I didn't recieve that right.

Comment: @KilingTime I get stuck at the "t" at the end of "Didn't"  so it becomes really hard to transition to the word "Do" but to me BoldBen's comment sounds the most helpful so far.

Comment: You can just say "din do", but you *must* stress the "din".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, John Lawler said:

The /t/ goes first, and the /n/ becomes syllabic and the second /d/ is tapped, so you wind up saying "did'n'do" (/'dɪɾṇ'du/).

Bold Ben said:
In Received Pronunciation there is a momentary pause between the 't' and the 'd' but in many dialects the 't' is dropped giving "I didn' do that".

Answer (score 1):

There's a thing I've heard from many people who live in the UK -- it's kind of like a glottal stop, but it's at the end of a word.

I've also heard this in Danish -- stronger and more frequently.

It's this sudden, closed off stop that you will need for this transition.  Use that technique in place of the final T in *didn't*, before you go on to "do."  With practice you'll learn to make that sudden stopping of sound very brief.

In the meantime, you could fudge with a substitute, e.g. *failed to do, neglected to do, forgot to do,* etc.

Comment: As I said in my comment I believe the gap to be more of a momentary pause than a glottal stop because when I do it the back of my tongue does not rise. Also I have almost as much difficulty with the transition from 'd' to 't' and between the two 't's in your examples as I do with the transition from 't' to 'd' in the question. I don't actully think that your fudge helps much if at all.